# Strange Tensorflow dimension mismatch

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning

I am running the following piece of code:

```
    obs = observation[0][0].reshape(self.n_features)
    actions_value = self.sess.run(self.q_eval, feed_dict={self.s: obs})
```

The shape of `obs` is: `(272,)`

and I have the error:

```
  File "qlearning/tf_dqn.py", line 124, in choose_action
    actions_value = self.sess.run(self.q_eval, feed_dict={self.s: obs})
  File "/Users/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 889, in run
    run_metadata_ptr)
  File "/Users/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1096, in _run
    % (np_val.shape, subfeed_t.name, str(subfeed_t.get_shape())))
ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape (272,) for Tensor u's:0', which has shape '(?, 272)'
```

The input dimension is exactly what has been specified in the placeholder, wtf?

Answer (score 0):

its seems you have one instance of features.
you need to reshape like this ,in your case batch_size is 1 i guess

```
 obs = observation[0][0].reshape(batch_size,self.n_features)
```

This is problem of not specifying if obs is colum vector or row vector,in your case, obs is a row vector, while in the placeholder,you specified a column vector